# Java yield() method does not work. Netbeans Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, ubuntu

I'm working with Threads in Java using Netbeans 6.9.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64. I have a problem using the method yield() because when I invoke this method the current thread keeps running instead of stopping and let other threads execution.

The code below it's an easy example to run 2 threads using yield. Instead of run the first thread, print one line and then stop the thread, the program finishes the thread 1 and then runs thread2, as the method yield is not called. I have tested this code on Windows and it works perfectly! so I wonder if there is any issue to use this method on Ubuntu or on 64bits platforms.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
//ThreadTest.java
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{
    public ThreadTest (String name){
        super(name);
    }
    public void run(){
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println(getName()+" - "+i);
            yield();
        }
        System.out.println(" END "+getName());
    }
}
```

//Main.java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest t1 =new ThreadTest("Thread1");
        ThreadTest t2 =new ThreadTest("Thread2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
   }
}

Comment: What makes you sure that the first thread is not yet finished, when you start the second thread?

Comment: Your test might be somewhat more accurate if you used a cyclic barrier to kick off both threads "at the same time" but I still wouldn't expect consistent results. Though single or dual core architectures are probably more likely to generate an interleaving behavior.

Answer (score 12):

`yield` is simply a request for another thread to be scheduled. There is nothing that prevents the JVM or underlying OS from scheduling the same thread again.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for `yield()` method in sun [JDK 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) and [JDK 7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) is different, you may need to check the javadoc for the version of JVM you are using.

Comment: +1 for noting the difference, though I think in this case the additional documentation is more of a clarification than a change.